# How to amalgamate aggregate function results, based on duplicate row values | SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, merge, sum, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to find the number of hours worked by the employees on each project in December...

Using Oracle DBMS.

So far I have the following...

```
SELECT c.clock_id, p.project_name, e.employee_first_name, e.employee_last_name, 
(clock_out - clock_in) * 24 AS hrs_worked_dec 
    FROM clock c
    LEFT JOIN employee e 
    ON c.employee_id = e.employee_id 
    LEFT JOIN project p
    ON p.project_id = c.project_id
    WHERE clock_in LIKE '%DEC%';
```

Currently, this is listing all the hours from my clock table, based on the calculation from the clock_in and clock_out columns.

However, I'm looking to amalgamate these results so that they show the sum for **each employee per project**, to give cleaner results.

Appreciate any help or guidance as to how to merge the results :-)

Answer (score 1):

You just need `GROUP BY` clause along with `SUM()` aggregation

```
SELECT p.project_name, e.employee_id, e.employee_first_name, e.employee_last_name, 
       SUM((clock_out - clock_in) * 24) AS hrs_worked_dec 
  FROM clock c
  LEFT JOIN employee e 
    ON c.employee_id = e.employee_id 
  LEFT JOIN project p
    ON p.project_id = c.project_id
 WHERE clock_in LIKE '%DEC%'
 GROUP BY p.project_name, e.employee_id, e.employee_first_name, e.employee_last_name
```

the last three columns within the `GROUP BY` list represent each distinct employee individually

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much! I've been breaking my brain trying to figure this out. Much appreciated :-)

Comment: you're welcome @rrup , please mark as the answer as helping.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `LEFT JOIN`? Are you expecting clock in without employee or project? You should use `INNER JOIN` And your solution is simple `group by` and `sum` as follows:

```
SELECT p.project_name, e.employee_id, e.employee_first_name, e.employee_last_name, 
       SUM((clock_out - clock_in) * 24) AS hrs_worked_dec 
  FROM clock c JOIN employee e ON c.employee_id = e.employee_id 
  JOIN project p ON p.project_id = c.project_id
 WHERE c.clock_in LIKE '%DEC%'
 GROUP BY p.project_name, e.employee_id, e.employee_first_name, e.employee_last_name
```

Also, `DEC` in `clock_in` will include all december's data (2020, 2019, ..) so use it carefully.

Comment: Yes any clock_in will always have employee_id and project_id, as this is the composite key. Thank you for this! :-)